# Preventing Numpy Slice/Index from changing the order of the output automatically

Tags: python, numpy

Hi basically it's easiest to show with the example below

```
testArray = np.array([[False, False, True, False], [False, False, True, False], [False, False, True, False], [False, True, False, False]]).T
wordArray = np.repeat(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 4).reshape(4,4)

testArray
>array([[False, False, False, False],
   [False, False, False,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True, False],
   [False, False, False, False]])

wordArray[testArray]
> array(['B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], dtype='<U1')
```

What I'm expecting is the order of my "indexing" to be preserved, so I want `array(['C', 'C', 'C', 'B'], dtype='<U1')` as the `testArray` appears.

Thanks

-EDIT-

Upon further testing (modifying the word array) it looks as if it just reverses the output instead of sorting it.  Does anyone know where to read more about this?  Is this 100% to happen?

I'm running numpy 1.21.5 and python 3.10

Comment: The ordering of your indexing is preserved. There is no sorting or reversing of the output.

Comment: To get your desired output: `wordArray.T[testArray.T]`; however, that is clearly a different command ;-).

Comment: why does that happen, I can also just do `[::-1]` at the end

Comment: Accidentally, reversing the output gives you the correct result. However, that won't be true in general.

Comment: For this indexing the (4,4) shape doesn't matter.  You get the same result if both arrays are raveled, shape (16,).  It's doing the selection element by element, not row by row or column by column (as you seem to want)

Answer (score 3):

The index was not changed and remained preserved.

```
import numpy as np

testArray = np.array([[False, False, True, False], [False, False, True, False], [False, False, True, False], [False, True, False, False]]).T
wordArray = np.repeat(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 4).reshape(4,4)

wordArray
array([['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
       ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
       ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
       ['D', 'D', 'D', 'D']], dtype='<U1')
testArray
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False]])
wordArray[testArray]
array(['B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], dtype='<U1')
```

### Explanation:

There is no `True` in `testArray[0]` so no `A`. In `testArray[1]` there's `True` at index 3 which is why there's B. In `testArray[2]` there are three True so `C, C, C`. And no `True` in the last column that's why no value of `D` from `wordArray[3]`.

If you wish to get that output(mentioned in question) then you need to transpose `wordArray` and not `testArray`:

```
testArray = np.array([[False, False, True, False], [False, False, True, False], [False, False, True, False], [False, True, False, False]])
wordArray = np.repeat(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 4).reshape(4,4).T
wordArray[testArray]
array(['C', 'C', 'C', 'B'], dtype='<U1')
```

---

Taking an example of two `6x4` arrays:

```
testArray = np.array([[False, False, True, False], [False, False, True, False], [False, False, True, False], [False, True, False, False], [False, True, True, False], [True, False, False, True]]).T
testArray
array([[False, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True]])
wordArray = np.repeat(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 6).reshape(4,6)
wordArray
array([['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
       ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
       ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
       ['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D']], dtype='<U1')
wordArray[testArray]
array(['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D'], dtype='<U1')
```

### Explanation:

In `testArray[0]`, `True` is at index 5. So, `A` from `wordArray[0]` is the output array's first element.
In `testArray[1]`, `True` is at index 3 and 4. So, `B` from `wordArray[1]` is the output array's second and third elements.
In `testArray[2]`, `True` is at index 0,1,2 and 4. So, `C` from `wordArray[2]` is the output array's fourth,fifth,sixth and seventh elements.
In `testArray[3]`, `True` is at index 5. So, `D` from `wordArray[3]` is the output array's last element.

---

### Conclusion:

Just print the arrays, go element-wise and check for `True` values. The value would be printed only if there's a `True` value on that **index**. So, the index is not shuffled/changed and remains preserved.

Comment: I guess I was using a 4x4 grid so it seems a bit indifferent, but if I use two 6x4 2d arrays it makes very little sense why it behaves in the way it does

Comment: @qwertylpc You can always print these arrays and try debugging on your own. That helps a lot!

Answer (score 2):

According to the `numpy indexing` docs, boolean array section:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing

```
If obj.ndim == x.ndim, x[obj] returns a 1-dimensional array filled with 
the elements of x corresponding to the True values of obj. The search 
order will be row-major, C-style.
```

That's the same as searching on the `ravel` arrays, which is also `row-major, C-style` (default that is)

```
In [92]: testArray.ravel()
Out[92]: 
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,
        True,  True, False, False, False, False, False])
In [94]: wordArray.ravel()
Out[94]: 
array(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D',
       'D', 'D', 'D'], dtype='<U1')
```

So the indexing is:

```
In [96]: wordArray.ravel()[testArray.ravel()]
Out[96]: array(['B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], dtype='<U1')
```

You could ravel in column-order:

```
In [97]: wordArray.ravel(order='F')[testArray.ravel(order='F')]
Out[97]: array(['C', 'C', 'C', 'B'], dtype='<U1')
```

That's equivalent to working with the transposes.

```
In [98]: wordArray.T[testArray.T]
Out[98]: array(['C', 'C', 'C', 'B'], dtype='<U1')
```

It may be easier to visualize this indexing by looking at the indices of the `True` values in `testArray`:

As a tuple of arrays, or as 2d array:

```
In [99]: np.nonzero(testArray)
Out[99]: (array([1, 2, 2, 2]), array([3, 0, 1, 2]))
In [100]: np.argwhere(testArray)
Out[100]: 
array([[1, 3],    # row 1, column 3, B
       [2, 0],    # row 2 all C
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```